# Measure of the relative complexity of equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, computational-complexity

Is there some measure to compare, in a straightforward way, the complexity of equations? Complexity seen as a function of basic operations involved for solving the equation, or as any other intuitive measure. For instance, from addition/subtraction to the most complex partial differential equations. I'm not a mathematician, so please bare with me.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but I'll keep my clothes on. "In a straight-forward way" - not really. There are some ways to approach complexity, but I strongly doubt you would consider them "straight-forward" at all. Anything straight-forward, would likely involve the creation of a hierarchy of operations, with a somewhat arbtrary ranking system, that would likely be disputed.

Comment: Agreed. Would your please list some of those?

Comment: First you want me to get naked, now to create lists. You can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory).